# Django admindocs ReStructuredText not working properly

Tags: django, restructuredtext

I am following this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/admindocs/) to generate my `Django V1.7` project docs but it is not working properly. For instance in the below mentioned model `BlogEntry`'s docstrings the links to `Blog.blog` and `auth.User` is not showing instead it is displaying as a plain text.

```
class BlogEntry(models.Model):
    """
    Stores a single blog entry, related to :model:`blog.Blog` and
    :model:`auth.User`.

    """
    slug = models.SlugField(help_text="A short label, generally used in URLs.")
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    ...

    def publish(self):
        """Makes the blog entry live on the site."""
        ...
```

But for the below mentioned view it working properly except in the heading.

```
def my_view(request, slug):
    """
    Display an individual :model:`myapp.MyModel`.

    **Context**

    ``RequestContext``

    ``mymodel``
        An instance of :model:`myapp.MyModel`.

    **Template:**

    :template:`myapp/my_template.html`

    """
    return render_to_response('myapp/my_template.html', {
        'mymodel': MyModel.objects.get(slug=slug)
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```